# Resolve user name from SID using only local information

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, sid

The Win32API function LookupAccountSID() allows to resolve the name corresponding to an SID. According to the documentation:
[LookupAccountSid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The LookupAccountSid function attempts to find a name for the specified SID by first checking a list of well-known SIDs. If the supplied SID does not correspond to a well-known SID, the function checks built-in and administratively defined local accounts. Next, the function checks the primary domain. Security identifiers not recognized by the primary domain are checked against the trusted domains that correspond to their SID prefixes.

Is there any way to look for the name only locally? That is, if the name is not found in the PC where the function is called, the function fails instead of checking the primary domain.

Edit: To be clear, I want to resolve the names of non-local users, without accessing the primary domain (only checking if the information has been stored locally)

Comment: You could invert the problem: determine if the SID is a domain SID and if so, don't look it up. Domain SIDs are those that start with S-1-5-21 and then *don't* use the [machine SID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113558/) for their domain value. What remains are built-in accounts and local accounts. Disclaimer: not tested.

Comment: The problem is I want to lookup information about domain users that has been stored locally. If a non-local user has logged in at some point, LookupAccountSid returns the correct name even if the computer is offline.

Comment: That's governed by the LSA cache. There's no official interface to that. There are tools that can dump it (like mimikatz) but those tend to be for hacking purposes and not welcomed with open arms by most network administrators. What exactly is your concern about looking up the information on the domain -- the fact that network traffic happens, the fact that the lookup might take a long time, something else? You could handle the timeout simply by canceling the lookup after a small time that a local lookup never exceeds.

Comment: If you just want to know which domain accounts have logged on to this machine, that's better handled by auditing and the security event log. The LSA cache isn't a reliable source of information for that, for starters, it can be disabled entirely on a machine as a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after but worth a shot:

```
byte[] sid = // your SID byte array
// Convert SID byte array to readable SID string
var sidString = (new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0)).Value;
var securityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(sidString);
var identity = securityIdentifier.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
// ... identity should be domain\user (string)
```

Comment: Nope, when using the SID of a domain user not present in the local PC, the above code looks up the information in the primary domain. Ideally, when using a SID not locally known, the code should not connect to an external resource.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

You could query the [`Win32_UserAccount` WMI class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx) for local accounts with the SID in question - if nothing is returned, the account doesn't exist on the local machine:

```
$SID = 'S-1-5-21-510807130-1270608819-2073245338-500'
if($user = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True' AND SID = '$SID'")
{
    $user.Name
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want information of non-local accounts. Calling LookUpAccountSid() with an SID of a domain user which has logged in at some point, returns successfully even if the computer is offline, which suggests that it is stored in a cache.